# E-mail fails to download due to virus error

Tags: windows-7, virus

Both Gmail and Yahoo Mail fail to download any files due to virus error since I upgraded my laptop to IE10 and the latest version of Gmail. IE10, Google Chrome and Firefox all do the same thing. The same downloads however work on my work computer using IE9. Can you please help?

My laptop runs Win7 Ultimate SP1 with SuperAntispyWare and Microsoft Security Essentials.

Both Gmail and Yahoo aborted the download for virus detection without identifying the virus. Same files were downloaded o.k. from other PC's. Clicking "Download" gets no response when I renamed the Window Defender folder. I have not play with SuperAntiSpyWare or MSE yet.

Comment: What virus do they think is in it?  What program is telling you there's a virus?  Are you SURE there's no virus (send them through virustotal.com if possible)?   If you turn off SuperAntiSpyware and/or MSE can you download it?

Comment: Warren, please log in with the same account you used for registering on this site. See here if you need to recover your credentials: http://superuser.com/users/account-recovery

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows Live Mail as your email client by chance? [What do I do if I can't download my attachments in Windows Live Mail?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/mail-email-download-attachments-troubleshoot-ui) I had a client where this option was ticked and they were unable to view any attachments...

Comment: Hi, Gmail and Yahoo Email declared virus detection at the end of download without identifying the virus. The same files were downloaded O.K. on other PC's that leads me to believe virus free. I have not tested without SuperantiSpyware or MSE yet.

Comment: Hi, Window Live Mail? Where can I get a copy?

Comment: @Warren, It's a part of Windows Essentials http://tinyurl.com/lj68ptk

Comment: @Warren, was the virus (assuming an attachment) detected by your endpoint AV or Yahoo and Gmail's Webmail scanner?